# How do I add client side validation of a dependent input using javascript and rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm guessing this is a pretty common procedure, but I had trouble looking up solutions since I'm not exactly how to phrase the question.  Basically I need to add a validation check for a drop down list that is dependent on another input selection, but the latter input is in another form.  Because of this, I imagine this means I need to validate against the database.  I'm trying to figure out a good method to do this, and would greatly appreciate suggestions.

To give more context, the two inputs are dependent upon each other.  The first is a list of air handler types.  This is the actual input:

```
<div class="field heating_type">
  <%= f.label :heating_air_handler_type_id, "Heating Type", :class => "required" %>
  <%= collection_select(:air_handler, :heating_air_handler_type_id, AirHandlerType.where("for_heating = ?", true).order("sort_order"), :id, :display_name, {}) %>
</div>
```

The other input is a list of plant types:

```
<div class="field plant_type">
  <%= f.label :plant_type_id, "Plant Type", :class => "required" %>
  <%= collection_select(:plant, :plant_type_id, PlantType.order("sort_order"), :id, :display_name, {}, { :class => "required" }) %>
</div>
```

Basically when a user selects an air handler heating type of 'Heat pump' I have to make sure that the plant type isn't a Chiller.  I also need this to work in the opposite direction so a user is warned if they select a chiller that it is not compatible with the heat pump selection.

If I haven't provided enough information, please let me know and I will fill in more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind the heating type select box using javascript/jquery with an onchange event.
Inside that mfunction you can change the values in the other list. Add or remove or just hide or disable. However you want to regulate the second select list.